# MS Access date comparison Macro

Tags: ms-access, macros

I am trying to write a Macro for a small Access DB so every time someone, opens the Table is checks the Expiry date column and if it was a week or less left on the date alert by a message box.

Something like:

```
 if(ExpiryDate <= NOW()+7) SHOW ERROR
```

Any easy way to do this?!

I work with SQL, but never done anything with Access before.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is pretty much correct. Maybe you could use

```
  if(ExpiryDate <= NOW()+7) 
  then
 msgbox("Expiration Date too long")
 end if
```

Access databases don't really have triggers, so you would need to put this in an 'After Update' event for that field.

Alternatively, you could supply a validation rule for that field. To do this, go to your table in design view, select your ExpiryDate field, click the "..." dialog to open your expression builder, and enter

```
   <= now() +7
```

You can supply validation text that will automatically be alerted to the user when they violate your rule.